# Is there a Wordpress Plugin like Imsanity that keeps high resolution originals?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, images

I'd like to show lower resolution photos on blog posts and their previews on the main page, but when clicked upon, they should still link to the full resolution version. Is there a plugin to do that automatically?

Comment: Please see the site's [tour] page what is considered off topic. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a plugin for that? Set image quality to 100% in WordPress with following code.

```
function my_new_image_quality( $quality ) {
    return 100;
}
add_filter( 'jpeg_quality', 'my_new_image_quality' );
add_filter( 'wp_editor_set_quality', 'my_new_image_quality' );
```

Now when you upload a image, WordPress always crop your image for different thumbnail sizes but it also keeps orignal image.

To get orignal image you can call

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?>
```

This will display full resolution original image.

Comment: You don't need to set the quality to 100% to cause this to happen. WordPress always keeps the original unaltered upload as the "full" size image, in all cases.

Comment: oh. Didn't know that. I thought WordPress scales down quality of all uploaded images including full size too.

Comment: The "full" size image is always the original copy of the file, unaltered. Only the downsized versions will be altered versions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just tested it. It works exectly like you said. Thanks @Otto